# $(A \otimes C) \oplus (B \otimes C) \cong (A \oplus B) \otimes C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A,B,C$ be R-modules. I know that _$\otimes C$ is an additive functor so $(A \otimes C) \oplus (B \otimes C)  \cong (A \oplus B) \otimes C$ but what should the isomorphism send $(a \otimes c,b \otimes \hat{c})$ to?

Answer (score 7):

Why not $a \otimes c + b \otimes \hat{c}$.  Nobody says the image has to be a pure tensor.